# how do I use the walker class to display categories in their correct heirarchy?

Tags: categories

One would think that returning categories using wordpress functions would automatically display them in their heirarchy? Ive noticed that categories dont necessarily do this, so I am trying to find a way to make sure they are returned correctly.

Comment: Are you *really* after using the walker class? Or was that just a proposal?

Comment: using the walker class is the only way to get categories in their heirarchy - should get_the_category($post->ID) display with heirarchy?

Answer (score 2):

There is number of functions that deal with categories. Some are meant to be used with other code and mostly deal with category objects, some are meant for displaying on front-end and outputting HTML.

[`wp_list_categories()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories) for example is meant for front-end presentation and defaults to hierarchical display.

Comment: just found this which should be useful: http://www.phpclasses.org/package/6607-PHP-Convert-an-array-into-hierarchic-data.html

Comment: @Innate well that is also a walker-type class, just like WordPress uses internally. I'd try t ostick with WP rather than third party code for this. Does `wp_list_categories()` fit your needs?

Answer (score 0):

You could use get_categories with argument (child_of= 10, hierarchical=1)

I have done it and it traverses the categories tree starting from the category 10.